# Creating a cube with rounded corners in Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Is it possible to create a cube with rounded corners of custom radius in three.js and then be able to texture that cube with an image?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `RoundedBoxGeometry` from the three.js examples.

```js
const geometry = new RoundedBoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10, 6, 2 );
```

Import it into your project using a pattern like so:

```js
import { RoundedBoxGeometry } from './threejs/examples/jsm/geometries/RoundedBoxGeometry.js';
```

three.js r.131

Comment: definitely not what I'm looking for. I just wanted a cube with rounded corners

Comment: Here's a better solution that gives control of the round corner radius: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/round-edged-box-2/1448

Comment: Subdivision approach is now outdated / replaced by the Three.js module/class "three-rounded-box"

Comment: @OGSean Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For a simple and straightforward example of subdivision modifiers on cubes (and other basic geometries), check out

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Subdivision-Cube.html

Comment: I know it is an old answer, but I think something is wrong with this example as of today

Comment: Yes, SubdivisionModifier has become out-of-date and hasn't worked correctly for a while... (currently Three.js r64)

Answer (score 1):

Fast forward a decade, welcome to the 20s.

Looks like this might be the modern solution now:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-rounded-box

Also on Three.js github someone made a rounded rectangle geometry in 2016 here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8402

There is also this approach from 2017 using extrude and a custom geometry:

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/round-edged-box/1402

This shape example also contains lots of shapes with rounded corners incl. a cube/box:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html