# to make the cube into rounded corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, 3d, three.js

How can I make a cube with rounded corners using three.js? I've read that it cant be done using css. Can someone tell me how to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/8YK2n/embedded/result/

```
/*
|------------------------------------------|
| MelonHTML5 - 3D Cube Gallery             |
|------------------------------------------|
| @author:  Lee Le (lee@melonhtml5.com)    |
| @version: 1.02 (09 Jan 2013)             |
| @website: www.melonhtml5.com             |
|------------------------------------------|
*/
Gallery = {
    _config: {
        speed: 500,
        size: 100,
        lightbox: !0,
        closeOnEsc: !0,
        animation: "default",
        slideshow: !1,
        slideshow_speed: 3E3,
        cube_speed: 1E3
    },
    lightbox_speed: 300,
    window_width: null,
    window_height: null,
    _cube_timeout: null,
    _gallery: null,
    _overlay: null,
    _lightbox: null,
    _current: null,
    _in_slideshow: !1,
    init: function () {
        Gallery._buildContainer(!0, !0);
        Gallery.window_width = $(window).width();
        Gallery.window_height = $(window).height();
        $(document).keydown(Gallery.Events.keyDown);
        $(window).resize(Gallery.Events.windowResize);
        Gallery._startCube()
    },
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994175/creating-a-cube-with-rounded-corners-in-three-js/12994218#12994218

Comment: @WestLangley thanks for your reply....  but i dont know how to change my alreay existing code....can u tell how to do it....

Comment: No, sorry. You have only tried for 2 minutes so far.

Comment: before posting it i look at the question and tried it

Comment: You need to show what you have tried -- preferably a live three.js example, and then ask a specific question.

Comment: i am asking suggestion i have tried 3d cube in css3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25317/discussion-between-user2045025-and-westlangley)

Comment: I think WestLangley is trying to say that this isn't a place to have other people do your work.  He answered the question with a very good example that shows how to use THREE.SubdivisionModifier.  If you took the time to look at the code you'd see how to do it.

Comment: @CrossphireDevelopment: thanks for your reply....can you tell what does this mean THREE.SubdivisionModifier

Comment: There is a class in Three.js called THREE.SubdivisionModifier.  It adds more triangles to an existing geometry like a CubeGeometry.  In the process of adding more triangles, the corners of the cube will start to become rounded.  Look at these lines.

var smooth = THREE.GeometryUtils.clone( cubeGeometry );
 var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier( 2 );
 modifier.modify( smooth );

Comment: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/modifiers/SubdivisionModifier.js should i need to look into this file

Comment: Yes, that is the correct file.

Comment: but i could not find this variable var smooth in the file

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to an example of three.js code that uses the Subdivision Modifier, which will produce a rounded cube.

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Subdivision-Cube.html